# Can you use the Google Safe Browsing API without downloading and caching the entire list?

Tags: php, google-api, safe-browsing

I'm just getting started with the Google Safe Browsing API to verify destination URLs for my URL shortening service http://lin.cr. Do I *have* to download the entire list of suspicious sites or is there a way I can run a check only when I need it?

I don't have a crazy amount of traffic on the site, so I think it's easier to do it live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that doing any kind of "live" stuff would be OK, considering the [Acceptable Usage in Clients](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/developers_guide.html#AcceptableUsage) part of the documentation *(quoting a few sentences)* :

> The second update request should
>   happen between 15-30 minutes later.
>   After that, each update should occur
>   once every 25-30 minutes.

And the paragraph after that one is pretty interesting, too :

> To help maintain a high quality of
>   service, it may be necessary for the
>   update server to ask the client to
>   make less frequent requests.

Considering these, I would not do any king of "live" request : I'm afraid google wouldn't quite like it...

Comment: Damn. Any idea how big the list is?

Comment: I have absolutly no idea, sorry -- but you can download it via some kind of cronjob, I'd say, independantly of the webapplication that uses it.